# MassTransit: Generic Consume Filters independent for each consumer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

First of all, excuse my English, it's very bad. I am using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus for asynchronous communication between microservices. I need to use middleware consume filters to get metadata from message.

Currently I have several consumers that "consume" different messages, but all from the same receive endpoint. Each one of these consumers has its own "ConsumeFilter" (zero, one or more), which are filters for scopes of type *IFilter<ConsumeContext>* and are registered in the "ConsumerDefinition " class of each consumer, with the method *.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(TFilter <>), context)*, with the intention that each consumer will only have its filter applied.
However, the filters must be "being added" to the endpoint receiver since when I receive a message, it goes through all the filters defined in all consumers.

**Is it possible that regardless of whether all consumers are connected to the same receive endpoint, only the filters of their consumer are applied to each message?**

Thank you very much.

Regards

Borja

Comment: I've never seen such excellent 'very bad' English in my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have consumer specific filters, you have several options. You can create a filter that is either:

1. Specific to a message type `ConsumeContext<TMessage>`
2. Specific to a consumer type `ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer>`
3. Specific to a consumer and message type `ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>`

In the message-specific case, you can configure that on the receive endpoint. In this case, the filter executes before the consumer.

In the consumer-specific cases, you can configure those on the consumer configurator (the second argument to `Configure`, in the `ConsumerDefinition`). These would be invoked after the consumer has been created, but prior to dispatching the message to the `Consume` method.

I [produced a video](https://youtu.be/Y4Z5puk4jW4) showing how each of these options works.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I have seen the video, it is very clear and very useful. I have a new question. In the video the filters shown are not scope filters, and according to the documentation the scope filters only work for filters that implement `IFilter<ConsumeContext<TMessage>>`. It is possible to implement a scoped filter that implements another type of consumer-based filter, such as a filter of type `IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer>>` or `IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>>`? Is there an alternative to doing this or is it not recommended?
Regards